# C# / C++ in same solution - DllImport not finding DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, interop, dllimport

I have a solution with a C++ dll project and a C# project that uses it. The problem is that the build path of the c++ project is in the solution folder and the c# is in the project's `bin` folder (each nested with debug/release), so the `DllImport` doesn't find them.
Is there a standard way to fix this?

Comment: Have you added the dll to the project references?

Comment: @Tudor Yes (non-blank-filler)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are supposed to do this is to set the build path for both projects to the same 'bin' directory... preferrably one for the solution, not a project.  Then just make all projects build to that one folder.  You can change that from the Project settings.

Another technique is to use a post-build step for the C++ app that copies the DLL to the C# project's folder.  That way you don't actually change any paths.  You just copy over a DLL.  Be careful here though because when you clean the C++ file's project, you may actually still have the copy in the C# projec'ts bin directory leaving you scratching your head as to why things aren't happening as expected.

Alternately, you can deploy the C++ DLL to a system path (also as part of a post-build step) but you'll have the same issues as stated above.

For debugging, I'd recommend these in the order presented.